# How can I unlock stage 6?

Tags: amazing-breaker

I love playing *Amazing Breaker* but I've been waiting for stage 6 for so long. Do I have to score a certain amount to move on to stage 6, or is it just a waiting game?

Answer (score 1):

There is no stage 6.  There are 5 stages with 20 levels each for a total of 100 levels.

http://www.amazingbreakerwalkthrough.com/